# Webcam taking pics with any action on my part

Tags: webcam

Using UM 16.04

Cheese keeps taking pictures by itself.

How can I stop that?

I have tried re-installing with no change.

Tried Guvcview and it is doing the same thing. ??

Can someone help me diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Camorama.

No more mysterious uninitiated picture taking. :-)